# jquery load an image

Tags: jquery

I have the following html code, in which if I click the image button 'button.png', the corresponding image 'image.png' will show in the 'content' div:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <a href="/static/images/image.png" class="content">
      <img src="/static/images/button.png" class="button">
  </a>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.content').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(url);
      return false
  });
```

However, I couldn't get the image displayed correctly (a mess of codes show up). Please help. Thanks.
    });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `load` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) will try to load the given URL as HTML and insert that HTML into the selected node. A PNG is not HTML, so `load` will not work. Instead, add an `img` element with an appropriate `src`. That might be implemented like so:

```
$('<img>').attr('src', url).appendTo('#content');
```

You may want to clear the `content` `div` before appending, however, so images do not build up. For that, you can use [`empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.content').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('<img src="'+url+'">').appandTo("#content");
});
```

because to display an image you have to use `<img>` tag. And [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) helps to create a new DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You are so close to complete it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.content').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').html($("<img/>").attr('src',url));
    return false
  }
);
```

You can use html() method to empty/replace whole div contents.